# Can I show my iOS app in the dock when it is restarted by the Location Services?

Tags: ios, service, location, dock

I have an iOS app that uses the Location Services in background for continuous location gathering. But when it is killed and then restarted by the Location Services (and thus the AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` called with the option `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey`), I would like that my user can know that it is still running in background.

I know that by looking through the Location Services applications list, a user can see what application used the Location Services recently, but I would like my users to know more easily that my app is still running and gathering locations. My prefered way would be to show my app in the dock, like it was manually started, but I don't know how. Is it possible? Would this be a bad practice?

Otherwise I could show a notification, but I do not want to bother my users with notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for this to happen. If the user kills your app and it is re-lauched by location services it will not show in the dock.

You could possibly show a local notification to the user when the app is launched by location services which would allow them to quickly launch the app however I don't believe this to be good practice.

EDIT:

I haven't tried this but it could possibly work, if I was at a computer right now I would test it.

1. Register your app with a [custom URL scheme](https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-ios-programming-alasdair-allan-2nd/chapter-12/custom-url-schemes).
2. In the `didFinishLaunching` is called, check it see if it's from location services.
3. If it's launched from location services do this to open the app: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"app://..."]];`

Again I have no idea if this will work or what will happen but it's worth a shot for the boss man.

Comment: Ah, I see. Let me see if I can find it explicitly stated in the docs

Comment: Well I couldn't find anything where it is explicitly stated. One of those things that everyone knows but isn't written which is a pain to explain to bosses I know, see my edits for a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you I will try it soon enough. If it works, I guess it would launch the application in foreground, which could be very frustrating for a user. But maybe my boss will like it more!...

Comment: After having some thoughts about it, I am pretty sure Apple will not like it if my app pops up from nowhere...

Comment: Yea, Apple would reject it but I wasn't sure if it was going to be deployed internally.